# Laravel 9 presence channels for all users (guests and logged)

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher, channel, user-presence

There are many similar topics, but no solution is correct.

I need to be able to "authenticate" logged in users and guests for a specific presence channel only. How can I achieve this?

The rest of the channels are to be available as standard only to logged in users.

Comment: Hello @60poro welcome to stackoverflow, please read the article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrase your question so that it is understood in the best possible way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this the other day and it's just for a game so make up your own mind, but it looks okay to me. Maybe you can give me some security feedback ;D My situation is using token based auth with laravel sanctum.

If you want to use the presence channel, you need to have a user object for the guests too.

```
Broadcast::channel('{userRoom}', function ($user) {
    return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
});
```

My solution was having a guest model and sql table in addition to the regular users table for fully authed users. In my case, both user and guest models have a room property, a string, the users can create a room, and guests can join that room.

Have a seperate end point for guest authentication. I gathered a name, device name, and room, because for a game it made sense, but the point is that it was passwordless. The route returns a guest object and a bearer token that the guest can use to 'authenticate' themselves.

In config/auth.php add the new model to user providers:

```
      'providers' => [
        'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Models\User::class,
          ],
          'guests' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Guest::class,
          ]
       ],
```

Then just make sure your guests are supplying the bearer token when they set up their pusher instance. Javascript would be something like:

```
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
      cluster: 'ap4',
      authEndpoint: "https://example.com/broadcasting/auth",
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      }
    })

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-xxxx');

    channel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", function () {
      console.log("Subscription succeeded")
      console.log(channel.members.me)
      ...
```

I guess just make sure you aren't giving the guests access to stuff they aren't supposed to get into. It's basically like having user roles.

Comment: ,AUthorization really required ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to know that private and presence channels are for authenticated and authorized users only.

if you want to broadcast for all you need to use public channel